# cp with reflink flag: how system determines if reflink is possible?

Tags: copy, filesystems, posix, glibc, gnu-coreutils

When I copy a file using reflink option, e.g.,

```
cp --reflink foo bar
```

how and what stage in execution of cp determines if the underneath file system supports COW. I tried looking into `coreutils/src/cp.c` but couldn't find the specific system call/ ioctl or any other method which determines COW capability and accordingly proceeds for cp execution / reports error:

```
cp: failed to clone 'bar' from 'foo': Bad address
```

In short, I am looking for how resolution of `--reflink=auto` option happens.

Answer (score 1):

`BTRFS_IOC_CLONE` or `FICLONE` are the ioctl request codes tried by `cp`. The former is for BTRFS reflinks while The latter got introduced when XFS gained [1] reflink support. You can strace the `cp` command to see what is happening in the version that you have.

[1] http://lwn.net/Articles/702633/

Comment: @vishal-sahu Does this answer your question? If yes, please the reply as an answer.